# Plotly doesn't show charts on Spyder (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap, spyder

I'm trying to learn how to plot a Heat Map on Python
Therefore I've download the library Plotly and I'm very new at it
I was trying to see if I could get the example code of plotly to work, but I failed, because I didn't have an account. I created my account and run the code

```
    import plotly
    #plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='julirov', 
    api_key='$$$$$$$$')
    import plotly.plotly as py
    import plotly.graph_objs as go

    trace = go.Heatmap(z=[[1, 20, 30],[20, 1, 60],[30, 60, 1]])
    data = [trace]
    py.iplot(data, filename='basic-heatmap')
```

I made my account (with my api_key too) and when I run the code, I've got this message:

```
    High five! You successfully sent some data to your account on 
    plotly. View your plot in your browser at 
    https://plot.ly/~julirov/0 or inside your plot.ly account where it 
    is named 'basic-heatmap'
```

The thing is: I want to see the chart on my Spyder, and not on a Website
Is that possible with Plotly? Or do I have to use another package?
Thank you!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, Plotly plots can't be displayed in Spyder. You need to use the Jupyter notebook for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plotly offline (no account needed).  Spyder runs the code to generate a local plot (in an HTML file) which is then viewed via your web browser:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot

trace = go.Heatmap(z=[[1, 20, 30],[20, 1, 60],[30, 60, 1]])
data = [trace]
plot(data, filename='basic-heatmap.html')
```

You use Spyder to develop the plot (file), and the browser to view it.

Answer (score -1):

The issue may have to do with the renderer.  To set the renderer in spyder, you can use the following:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "svg"
```

Anaconda may not have Orca installed natively, so in the Anaconda terminal, you may have to install it:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly-orca
```

From there, you can use plotly express to create the heat map (code pulled from here: https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/).  You should not need an account to use plotly express – it will render locally by default.

```
import plotly.express as px

trace = go.Heatmap(z=[[1, 20, 30],[20, 1, 60],[30, 60, 1]])
data = [trace]
plot(data, filename='basic-heatmap.html')
```

[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaCFv.png)